# AS3Crypto RSA Signing

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, rsa, as3crypto

I'm having some troubles matching the value returned from RSA signing
a Base64 SHA1 hash in the actionscript as3crypto library with the result returned in c#.

I'm passing in a Base64 hash decoded as a byte array to the sign()
function provided in as3crypto and base64 encoding the result.
However, this result never matches the returned result from a c#
function which performs the same task.  Does it matter that the
function takes in and returns hex even though it works at the byte
array level?

Please see my below signing function to check i haven't missed
anything!

```
private function signHash(hashInBase64:String):String
{
       var src:ByteArray = Base64.decodeToByteArray(hashInBase64);
       var key:RSAKey = getRSAKey();
       var dst:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

       key.sign(src, dst, src.length);

       return Base64.encodeByteArray(dst);
}
```

Anyone had much experience with the AS3Crypto library?

Any help would be great!!!

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: "Does it matter that the function takes in and returns hex even though it works at the byte array level?" ... did you mean, it takes in bas 64, or did you really mean it takes in hex ... maybe that is the problem? base 64 and hex are significantly different ... any hex value is a almost a valid base64 value (except that base 64 is always padded to a length dividable by 4), so the decoder will probably take it ...

Comment: also, what do you get, when you verify the signature? does it work?

Comment: The signing algorithm takes in a bytearray but all the examples are from hex to a bytearay, so i convert base64 to a byte array, would they convert to the same bytes? verification doesn't work either, trouble with this library is there is no documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your C# version is using [RSA PKCS #1 version 1.5](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125). The standard computes signatures by doing an RSA private key operation over a byte string composed as

```
0x00 0x01 || 0xff* || 0x00 || OID || hash
```

Looking at the as3crypto code shows that the RSAKey class does not add any OID during the sign operation. Hence if you don't do it you'll get incorrect results.

Looking at the code also shows that as3crypto is vulnerable to [this attack](http://www.imc.org/ietf-openpgp/mail-archive/msg14307.html), because it does not verify the padding properly. This attack is more than 3 years old. Hence it seems like a good to use a different library than as3crypto.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other library, thanks for the information though!

Answer (score 0):

Now there is an ActionScript crypto library compatible with .NET. Here it is: http://code.google.com/p/flame. Looks like it supports RSA exactly the way .NET does.