# signature verification RSA in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, verification, public-key-encryption

I have PEM encoded X.509 version 3 certificate. Also I have public key, signature and message. How can I check if this signature is original (true) ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154373/459963). Might be helpful. Currently, it doesn't support the PEM encoding but provides .NET-compatible RSA signature verification.